# Mujoco. Meshes are too big

Tags: cad, mujoco

I made small models in FreeCAD and Rhinoceros 3D (cm to m), when I import them to Mujoco, they are giants with giant masses, and I have to multiply gravity by 100 (and probably other options) to make them act normal. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`<mesh>` tag](https://mujoco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/XMLreference.html#asset-mesh) has a `scale` attribute that you can use to scale your mesh size, e.g. `scale="0.01 0.01 0.01"`.

Alternatively, the default gravity value is expressed in meters per second^2, so if you can configure your CAD software to output vertex coordinates in meters you should get the right size.